# not able to display records as per page size in kendo grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

i want to perform filtering,sorting and no of records in kendo grid but it is not working.

this is my view page:

```
<script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#categories-grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "json",
                            transport: {
                                read: {
                                    url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("categoriesList", "Admin"))",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    data: '',
                                }
                            },
                            schema: {
                                data: "Data",
                                total: "Total",
                                errors: "Errors"
                            },
                            error: function(e) {
                                display_kendoui_grid_error(e);
                                // Cancel the changes
                                this.cancelChanges();
                            },
                            pageSize: 2,
                            serverPaging: true,
                            serverFiltering: true,
                            serverSorting: true
                        },
                        pageable: {
                            refresh: true,
                            pageSizes: [10,20,30]
                        },
                        editable: {
                            confirmation: false,
                            mode: "inline"
                        },
                        scrollable: false,
                        columns: [{
                            field: "CategoryName",
                            title: "CategoryName",
                            width: 100
                        }, {
                            field: "CategoryId",
                            title: "Edit",
                            width: 100,
                            template: '<a href="/Admin/ViewCategoryDetails?categoryId=#=CategoryId#&categoryName=#=CategoryName#">Edit</a>'
                        }]
                    });

                });

            </script>
```

This is my controller side http post action:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult categoriesList(DataSourceRequest command)
        {
            Categories categoriesBal = new Categories();
            List<CategoryModel> categoriesList = new List<CategoryModel>();
            var category = GetCategory();

            ViewBag.Category = GetCategory();
            List<Category> categoryDetails = categoriesBal.fetchCategory();//here i am fetching categoryid,name            
            var gridModel = new DataSourceResult
            {
                Data = categoryDetails.Select(x =>
                {
                    var categoryModel = new CategoryModel();
                    categoryModel.CategoryId = x.CategoryId;
                    categoryModel.CategoryName = x.Name;                        
                    return categoryModel;
                }),
                Total = categoryDetails.Count
            };
            return Json(gridModel);

        }
```

This is my DataSourceRequest class

```
public class DataSourceRequest
    {
        public int Page { get; set; }

        public int PageSize { get; set; }

        public DataSourceRequest()
        {
            this.Page = 1;
            this.PageSize = 10;
        }
    }
```

This is my Category model:

```
 public class CategoryModel
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public int frequency { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<SubcategoryModel> subCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

i am having **12 category**.when i am setting **item per page dat is 2** it display **all records.**

can any body tell me what is the problem in my code and how to **perform sorting and filtering??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your schema to act as a function

```
schema: {
   data: function(response) {
    return response.Data ; 
   }
   total: function(response) {
     return response.Total; 
   }
},
```

and pageable to

```
pageable: {
 refresh: true,
 pageSizes: [2,10,20,30]
},
```

and do not see the use of DataSourceRequest in your code since you don't send the pageSize from the read . send a object of DataSourceRequest  and return only what is specify in your DataSourceRequest . in this case only two records

```
transport: {
            read: function (options) {

               var commandOBJ=[{
                    Page: 1, // Once the first two item is loaded and you click for the next page you will have the page in "options" (should be like options.page)
                    PageSize:2 
                }];

                $.ajax({
                    url:"@Html.Raw(Url.Action("categoriesList", "Admin"))",
                    data: { command: bookmarkID },
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        options.success(result);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        options.error(result);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Now from your action categoriesList check the command and send data accordingly . and your read action can be a GET instead of POST . hope this Helps

Comment: can u please write your whole script bcz half u have written up half dwon so i am not getting it and also post ur controller logic.plz plz plz plz .i am very much new in mvc so please send ur whole script along with controller.

Comment: Dear friend , you just have to replace the schema , pageable and transport with your script and your categoriesList Action is nothing to do with MVC. Its simply Programming Logic . I'm here to Guide you.

your action logic should be , look at the command parameter pagesize and page and return the appropriate  result . like at first load pagesize is 2 and page is 1 , so return only two records . once you do paging you JS dataSource read will send the page and pagesize . Then from your action send the second set of data if the page 2 and size is 2 .

Comment: yaa i understand bt my controller logic will be same because as u r saying that method fire will be of get instead of post/.

Comment: yaa i understand but my controller logic will be the same? and what about post method dat i am using.do i need to change dat.

Comment: your  controller logic should change and as I explain in the previous comment . yes change it to a GET method since my code (DataSource read ) does a Get Ajax call.

Comment: sorry my dear friend as i am very mcuh new to mvc i wont be able to use your solution.if possible can u please provide me the script and controller logic.if possible

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using your custom **DataSourceRequest** class, use the **KendoGridMvcRequest** class from [this project](http://github.com/StefH/KendoGridBinderEx), this class correctly maps the paging, sorting and filtering.

Also available as [nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/KendoGridBinderEx).

See this [link](http://kendogridbinderex.apphb.com) for demo.

Comment: i am not using dll of kendo grid.i am using css and js of kendo.cant u edit my code and provide me solution??

Comment: When using the KendoGridBinderEx project, you don't need any Kendo dll's, only only the JS and CSS version (free edition)

Comment: Sorting and filtering will work fine when using KendoGridBinderEx

Comment: yaa but i dont want to use that.have u use it??

Comment: I'm using KendoGridBinderEx because I've developed it. Please take a look at the source code on github to see how it's used

Comment: ya i have lloked but i want 1 demo project in mvc.there lots of file are there so i am not getting it.i want 1 demo project in mvc